# Faster Way to GroupBy Apply Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandas-apply

How can I make the Groupby Apply run faster, or how can I write it a different way?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],\
                   'value':[1,2,np.nan,3,np.nan,1,2,np.nan,4,np.nan]})

result = df.groupby("ID").apply(lambda x: len(x[x['value'].notnull()].index)\
                    if((len(x[x['value']==1].index)>=1)&\
                    (len(x[x['value']==4].index)==0)) else 0)
```

output:

```
Index  0  
1      3  
2      0
```

My program runs very slow right now. Can I make it faster? I have in the past filtered before using groupby() but I don't see an easy way to do it in this situation.

Comment: There is parallel_apply which is introduced lately -> https://towardsdatascience.com/pandaral-lel-a-simple-and-efficient-tool-to-parallelize-your-pandas-operations-on-all-your-cpus-bb5ff2a409ae

Comment: hi. could you explain what you are trying to achieve. you could get better speeds by using Pandas' vectorized methods

Comment: hi. after grouping, i want to count the number of values in the group if the group contains a value (1 in this example) and does not contain another value (4 in this example). How can I use Pandas' vectorized methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you need. I have decomposed it a bit, but you can easily method-chain it to get the code more compact:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        "value": [1, 2, np.nan, 3, np.nan, 1, 2, np.nan, 4, np.nan],
    }
)

df["x1"] = df["value"] == 1
df["x2"] = df["value"] == 4

df2 = df.groupby("ID").agg(
    y1=pd.NamedAgg(column="x1", aggfunc="max"),
    y2=pd.NamedAgg(column="x2", aggfunc="max"),
    cnt=pd.NamedAgg(column="value", aggfunc="count"),
)

df3 = df2.assign(z=lambda x: (x['y1'] & ~x['y2'])*x['cnt'])

result = df3.drop(columns=['y1', 'y2', 'cnt'])
print(result)
```

which will yield

```
    z
ID   
1   3
2   0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is agg() much faster than apply()?

Comment: I would assume that my solution is faster than yours with  lambda functions, because it works on the whole vector in parallel. But I would be interested to hear how it works on your larger dataset.

Comment: It was perfect. Thank you. It was multiples times faster than mine due to vectorization.